# cart with custom icon with number text android

Tags: android, drawable, padding, cart

I have cart icon which looks customized, I want to show the number in the white space of the icon 
what alignment attribute should I use ?

I tried with `padding` but `double digit number` looks ugly

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/btn_cart"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:background="@drawable/shopp_cart"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"       
          android:gravity="right|bottom"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:paddingTop="20dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
```

This is the custom icon [image]

Comment: Use `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: this will display the text on blue colored image , but i wanted it on the center of white color..This is a single image NOT two separate

Comment: Oh. Okay then decrease text size by 2 numbers or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use This. It will help You. Use One Image View and One Text View to show Icon and text

Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="17dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your icon will look like this

[image]